# Which should I use AAAsViewController or AAAListViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, naming

"s" or "List", Which should I use?

ex) BooksViewController or BookListViewController

Comment: what about BooksTableViewController? or BooksCollectionViewController

Comment: thanks, why should not I use 'list'?

Comment: How about BookListScreen?? "ViewController" is too long a name anyways :P

Comment: There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things. -- Phil Karlton

Comment: @bseh I thought it was memory leaks :D

Comment: Because I dont like "Lists"... the responses you get will be peoples individual preference, so this question is not a good fit for StackOverflow and will likely be closed by the community. Use what works for you

Comment: List is not an iOS terminology. I'll go with the first as its short and has meaning. `BooksVC` to shorten it more :P. I would say use `BooksTableViewController` only if you're sub-classing `UITableViewController`.